# How to add an attachment and the file should be less than 35 MB size

Tags: flutter, dart

Like in Email, i need to show an option **attachment** it should show the option like browse or drag and drop , and the attached file should be less than 35MB. How to achieve in flutter.

Answer (score 1):

To pick file use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) plugin.

Code for picking file:-

```
FilePickerResult result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();

if(result != null) {
   PlatformFile file = result.files.first;
   if(file.size>36700160)//if size greater than 35MB
        {
          result=null;
          print('Size greater than 35MB');//or show the toast 
        }
} else {
   // User canceled the picker
}
```

Now use this result to upload the file:-

```
RaisedButton(
   child:Text("Upload")
   onPressed:(){
     if(result!=null)
        uploadFile();//call your function for upload.
  }
),
```

Comment: i am getting error in if(file.bytes>36700160) , bytes is Uint8List. The operator '>' isn't defined for the type 'Uint8List'.

Comment: Have updated the code replace file.bytes with file.size